# C# - How to read the values of the Pivot table in an excel file using openXML?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, pivot, openxml

I'm reading an excel file with a pivot table. I'm using openXML to read the values of the excel file. I'm able to get the values of other cells outside the pivot table using "cell.cellvalue.innertext". However when reading cells inside the pivot table, I'm getting "%%=[ResourceTrend_MainQuery].[Name]" instead of the actual vaue.

Could someone show a sample c# code for getting the values of cells inside a pivot table in an existing excel file?

So far I've tried cell.cellvalue.innertext and cell.cellvalue.ToString() but didn't get the expected result.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

 namespace Framework
{   
    public class ExcelValidation
    {   
            public string GetCellValue(string fileName, string sheetName, string addressName)
        {   
            string value = null;

            // Open the spreadsheet document for read-only access.
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = 
                SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
            {
                // Retrieve a reference to the workbook part.
                WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;

                // Find the sheet with the supplied name, and then use that 
                // Sheet object to retrieve a reference to the first worksheet.
                Sheet theSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().
                Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();

                // Throw an exception if there is no sheet.
                if (theSheet == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("sheetName");
                }

                // Retrieve a reference to the worksheet part.
                WorksheetPart wsPart = 
                    (WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id));
                
                // Use its Worksheet property to get a reference to the cell 
                // whose address matches the address you supplied.
                Cell theCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().
                Where(c => c.CellReference == addressName).FirstOrDefault();

                // If the cell does not exist, return an empty string.
                if (theCell.InnerText.Length > 0)
                {
                    value = theCell.CellValue.InnerText;
                    
                    // If the cell represents an integer number, you are done. 
                    // For dates, this code returns the serialized value that 
                    // represents the date. The code handles strings and 
                    // Booleans individually. For shared strings, the code 
                    // looks up the corresponding value in the shared string 
                    // table. For Booleans, the code converts the value into 
                    // the words TRUE or FALSE.
                    if (theCell.DataType != null)
                    {
                        switch (theCell.DataType.Value)
                        {
                            case CellValues.SharedString:
                                
                                // For shared strings, look up the value in the
                                // shared strings table.
                                var stringTable = 
                                    wbPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
                                
                                // If the shared string table is missing, something 
                                // is wrong. Return the index that is in
                                // the cell. Otherwise, look up the correct text in 
                                // the table.
                                if (stringTable != null)
                                {
                                    value = 
                                        stringTable.SharedStringTable
                                        .ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                                }
                                break;

                            case CellValues.Boolean:
                                switch (value)
                                {
                                    case "0":
                                        value = "FALSE";
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        value = "TRUE";
                                        break;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

[Sample excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfGMU.png)

Comment: Can you share a segment of your excel file content?

Comment: I attached an image for the excel file. The pivot table starts from row 13. I need to get the value under the Name column

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Update - I added my code to the description.